# Does 2D circular wave reduces amplitude as it spreads out in lossless medium?

Tags: waves

When we throw a pebble into water, a 2D circular wave is generated. Suppose the water here is completely lossless, will the wave amplitude still reduce as the wave front spreads out?

In the case of a 1D lossless and infinitely long string, the wave front will travel forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the amplitude will decrease due to spreading.  Energy must be conserved, and as the radius of the circular wavefront increases the energy at any single point must decrease proportionately.  Usually the square of a wave's amplitude is proportional to the energy density, and for circular waves the length of the wave increases with the radius.  Thus, the energy density must decay as one over the radius; taking a square root then suggests the amplitude will decay as one over the square root of the radius.

In 3D you follow the same logic to concluding the amplitude falls off as one over the radius.

In 1D, in the absence of any losses or reflecting surfaces, the amplitude will not decay at all.

It might be worth pointing out that these energy arguments do not apply only to water waves or string waves, but are general statements for all waves.